# User Authentication with Firebase and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, angularfire

I struggled with trying to get user authentication working in my angularJS/Firebase app for several days until I finally got it sort of working. The problem is that I know the solution I came up with is very hacked together and not the correct way to approach authentication. Plus, logging in seems to only work after the user taps the login button twice. I would appreciate it if anyone could provide guidance on the correct way to do this.

I have read some answers on SO related to this question, but they all seemed overly complicated for what I need. Simply put, if a user logs in, he or she should be able to access any view in the app. If the user is not logged in and tries to visit a url that requires authentication, he or she is sent back to the login screen. I also need to be able to access the current user's ID after he or she has logged in.

I am using email/password authentication via Firebase's simple login. Right now I am using an AuthService to notify the app controllers when the user's authentication state has changed (at least I think I am). If the user has logged in, I save the userID in session storage and then redirect to the Epics Feed page. I then have a user service that fetches the userID from session storage. Here's the code:

Authentication Service:

```
app.service('AuthService', function($rootScope, $location, $q, SessionService, angularFireAuth) {
    var epiclyRef = new Firebase('my firebase ref');
    this.auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(epiclyRef, function(error, user) {
        if (error) {
            $rootScope.$emit("loginError", error);
        } else if (user) {
            $rootScope.$emit("login", user);
        } else {
            $rootScope.$emit("logout");
        }
    });
    });
```

Login Controller:

```
app.controller("LoginController", function($scope,$location, $rootScope, $window, AuthService, SessionService){
$scope.credentials = { email: "", password: "" };

$scope.login = function(){
    AuthService.auth.login('password', {
        email:$scope.credentials.email, 
        password: $scope.credentials.password
    });
}

$rootScope.$on("login", function(event, user, $location) {
    // do login things
    var userId = user.id;
    SessionService.set('authenticated', true);
    SessionService.set('user', userId);
    $window.location = '#/epicsFeed';
});

$rootScope.$on("loginError", function(event, error) {
    // tell the user about the error
    console.log(error);
});
})
```

The user logs out from the nav menu, so the logout function is in a menu controller:

```
app.controller('MenuController',function($scope,$location, $rootScope, $window, AuthService, SessionService){
$scope.logout = function() {
    AuthService.auth.logout();
    $rootScope.$on("logout", function(event, $location) {
    // do logout things
        SessionService.unset('authenticated');
        SessionService.unset('user');
        $window.location = '/';
    })

  };
})
```

And to control which views the user can reach with/without authentication:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, SessionService){
        var routesThatDontRequireAuth = ['/', '/register'];
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function( event, next, current){
            if(!_(routesThatDontRequireAuth).contains($location.path()) && !(SessionService.get('authenticated'))){
                $location.path('/');
                console.log("Please login to continue");
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: What is the question? Does the code you have here not work?

Comment: On mobile, it only successfully logs in after tapping the login button twice. I also don't think this is the "proper" way to do this, given what I have seen from other posts on SO.

Comment: Just realized this behavior doesn't just happen on mobile...it happens on web too. It seems like the app is trying to redirect before the "authenticated" has been flagged as true in session storage on the first attempt. Then, once I tap the login button again, authenticated has been tagged as true, so logging in works.

Comment: I am having similar Firebase, AngularJS authentication/login questions. Can anyone explain a possible solution? Especially, utilizing https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire and its simpleLoginTool